# Joomla! K2 - extra fields for K2 category

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, custom-fields, joomla-k2

I need to attribute extra fields (image and textfield in my case) for a K2 category. I found extra fields attributions only for K2 Items, and for Users by extension (http://getk2.org/extend/extensions/73-user-extended-fields-for-k2) but not for categories.

**Joomla! :** *v2.5.14* / **K2 :** *v2.6.7*

Any solutions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of K2 (v2.6.9) is not capable of attaching extra fields to categories. However, according to the website, K2 v3 will have these capabilities:

> the new extra fields system can now extend any content entity in K2 (items, categories, tags, users etc.). This pushes further the development of K2 extra fields by developers for simple tasks, while maintaining the K2 plugin API for more advanced control and integration with other components or web services

http://getk2.org/blog/2073-first-beta-of-k2-version-3-is-here

If you're interested in beta testing, there is a team who has begun to develop a plugin for K2 v2.x that adds these features. You can find more info here:
http://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/37526-multiple-extra-field-groups?start=20#144681